# Passing arguments to sub-processed entry point

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose

Basically I want my program to be started subcommand of `/bin/sh -c`, so that I can <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> it and have it stop the process.

If I use this form.

```
ENTRYPOINT executable
```

It will convert to `/bin/sh -c 'executable'`, which gives me the ability to <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> but it prevents me from passing further arguments in the `COMMAND` when running e.g.

```
docker run executable arg1
```

Will still end up as `/bin/sh -c 'executable'`.

If I use define the ENTRYPOINT like so, using the array format.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "executable" ]
```

This will work.

```
docker run executable arg1
```

Start running as `executable arg1`, but <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> will not work as its not a subprocess of a shell.

Comment: Can you check my answer? I can't see error. Can you point me to some case, where you get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a write your own `docker-entrypoint.sh` script and use that to wrap your executable while also passing it arguments from the `docker` command.

Create a file called `docker-entrypoint.sh` with the following contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
executable "$@"
```

Then at the end of your `Dockerfile` use the following commands.

```
# Copy over the entrypoint script.
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

# Default entrypoint.
ENTRYPOINT [ "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Then you will be able to pass the executable in the container parameters like so.

```
docker run -it --rm image arg1
```

Which will run like this in the container.

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh arg1
    6 root       0:00 executable arg1
   16 root       0:00 sh
   22 root       0:00 ps faux
```

You will also be able to shutdown the container by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when attached.

Comment: `executable $@` is buggy. Needs to be `executable "$@"` or it will change `"hello world"` to two separate arguments, as in `"hello" "world"`.

Comment: Also, `set -e` has absolutely no value whatsoever on a one-line script: When an interpreter runs a single command, it *always* exits with the status of that command. (`set -e` is often a bad idea on larger scripts as well; see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), particularly the exercises that follow the allegory, and [this list of incompatibilities between different shells' implementations of `set -e`](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) -- note when reading it that the "Austin Group" are the maintainers of the POSIX sh standard).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your docker in **interactive** mode.

Use command `docker run -it`

> The **-it** instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the container.

**I have tried** to reproduce the problem you have faced.

Dockerfile I have used

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY hold.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./hold.sh"]
```

Shell script like `executable`

```
$ cat hold.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$@"

echo "waiting"
sleep 5m
```

Now I have build it and run

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run -it test "running"
running
waiting
^C⏎
```

Its working fine.

Comment: It probably works fine because you are running a shell script which will execute as a subprocess of a shell try something else that does not listen for SIGINT.

Comment: Can you give me a name of such process that doesn't listen for SIGINT?

Comment: OK I think the process does listen for SIGINT but for some reason its not receiving it, because maybe the program is not running in an interactive way?

Comment: Yes. Use interactive mode to see yourself. Please inform me if it works